# Can mechanize work with browsers?

Tags: ruby, web, automation, mechanize

I am using ruby's gem mechanize to automate a file upload after logging in to a particular site..
I am able to login using

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

#creating an object for Mechanize class
a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
# site refreshes after login
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
}

#Getting the page
a.get('https://www.samplesite.com/') do |page|
puts page.title
form = page.forms.first
form.fields.each {|f| puts f.name}
form['username'] = "username"
form['password'] = "password"

# Then submitting the form and reaching the page
```

Now there are two questions...
a. Can I see this happening on browser using any agent or tool?
b. Is there any way to keep the mechanize waiting for the page to load?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) ?
It should easily integrates with your Ruby program

Comment: Can I see the automation happening on browser?

Comment: Yes, WebDriver can run inside a real browser, this depends on your implementation - Firefox, Chrome, IE require real browser installed in order to operate.

Comment: Thanks.. will try hands on it but I really wanted to know if this can be done with mecahnize :)